# JAX-WS How to set Accept-Language

Tags: java, web-services, post, jax-ws

I am going to make this POST, but i also want to set the language I would like to receive my response in.

```
final String language = metadata.getLanguage(); //this is the string i want to send with the post
final String baseUrl = getProperty(BASE_URL_PROPERTY);

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
final WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl);
final WebTarget template = target.path("myURI");
final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = template.request(MediaTypes.ORDER_REQUEST_JSON);

final Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.json(orderRequest));
```

Can you please help me attach the language to the request somehow? 
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = template.request(MediaTypes.ORDER_REQUEST_JSON).acceptLanguage(language);
```